# how debug application using .wer files

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-error-reporting

I recently submitted application on windows marketplace and got the crashing report in .wer format. but I dont know how to understand the report to find out the problem.I am opening it into notepad but not able to understand anything and I am unable to open it in visual studio 2012.Kindly help

Here is the report content:

```
Version=1
EventType=MoAppCrash
EventTime=130416971751387322
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=130416971751699856
ReportIdentifier=b78d10da-c17e-11e3-8252-2cd05aaed19e
IntegratorReportIdentifier=b78d10d9-c17e-11e3-8252-2cd05aaed19e
WOW64=1
NsAppName=praid:App
Response.BucketId=TestBucket
Response.BucketTable=4
Response.LegacyBucketId=TestBucket
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Package Full Name
Sig[0].Value=14665AAQ.AAQ_1.0.3.11_neutral__mqjtjzf78eaaj
Sig[1].Name=Application Name
Sig[1].Value=praid:App
Sig[2].Name=Application Version
Sig[2].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[3].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[3].Value=5347e402
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[4].Value=combase.dll
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[5].Value=6.3.9600.16520
Sig[6].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[6].Value=52e6927e
Sig[7].Name=Exception Code
Sig[7].Value=800f1000
Sig[8].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[8].Value=0007fd17
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=896a
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=896a5d446a93e35895a2b8d22860148e
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=0488
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=04885d6165bbbf9c1e9404f1069bd19d
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\14665AAQ.AAQ_1.0.3.11_neutral__mqjtjzf78eaaj\AskAQuestion.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\14665AAQ.AAQ_1.0.3.11_neutral__mqjtjzf78eaaj\AskAQuestion.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\ebdd49343f711b2029293f8e621b28a2\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UIAutomationCore.DLL
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NInput.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\TWINAPI.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\actxprxy.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igd10iumd32.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc32.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MrmCoreR.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Bcp47Langs.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\8455c031f8ffe82a0109c563873260e8\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt0d283adf#\e209e80a78aee1367c92f1dd884d8f58\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runtc259d85b#\00fd6b9fc7353b024079f65164bdc73f\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\system32\windowscodecs.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\oleacc.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=MoAppCrash
AppName=14665AAQ.AAQ_mqjtjzf78eaaj!App
AppPath=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\14665AAQ.AAQ_1.0.3.11_neutral__mqjtjzf78eaaj\AskAQuestion.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=254467B9963B346A2B88CAE91E846F7F
```

Comment: Afaik those files are readably by humans. So what is the content?

Comment: @StefanFalk :Kindly see my question I updated with content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't debug application crashes with this .wer files.

The only useful information is the error code `800f1000`:

```
C:\Users\André>err 800f1000
# for hex 0x800f1000 / decimal -2146496512
  SPAPI_E_ERROR_NOT_INSTALLED                                    winerror.h
# No installed components were detected.
# 1 matches found for "800f1000"
```

You need a dmp file which you can get from the Quality Reports page and [debug it](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-64-Windows-81-Store-App-Crash-c000027b).